# How to set color of the Viewport Background?

Tags: color

Here is my view:
[image: view]

I want to make the floor less dark so my wireframe objects are not the same color as it.
I tried setting the background color on the world, but that has no affect.

I searched the Internet, but that only told me how to change the color of the grid lines
and none of the other preferences seemed to do what I want.

Anyone know how to do this?

In his answer to this question, Abraham Reinhardt showed me his Viewport Shading menu, but mine looks like this and does not have the same settings as his:
[image]

In a comment, Blunder suggesting setting the world background and strength.  I tried that and it did nothing.  Here is the menu I am editing:

[image]

Abraham Reinhardt also suggested changing the Viewport Display color, but that did not change anything either.  Here is a pic:
[image]

Comment: hello, what floor are you talking about? also, maybe share your file so that we can try

Comment: There’s no such floor in blender. The dark gray background you are seeing is the world background. I don’t know what setting you tried to change, but that color should change in viewport render (which is the viewport mode you are in) when you adjust the world shader color.

Comment: In the *World* settings you have set a bright color which is visible in the *Rendered* viewport shading mode (key Z). That's correct. But you have set the *Strength* to 0 which results in darkness. Set *World Properties > Surface > Strength* to 1. (I only wonder why it's not pure black in your screenshot)

Comment: @moonboots -- I believe Neil is talking about a color in the "Preferences >> Themes >> 3d Viewport" ... somewhere...

Comment: @Blunder I set the I am in the rendered viewport.  I set the strength to 1 and the color to red, but the view did not change.  I can't figure out how to add an image to this comment so I will edit my original post to show the menu I edited.

Comment: See below, you need to enable Scene World in your Viewport Shading panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a rendered viewport, with Scene World disabled.

I include an example where I *enabled Scene World*, that then uses the World color/nodes:

[image]

And then in World Properties -- with Use Nodes enabled -- I changed the background color:

[image]

Of course, as the world color may be reflected off of the other objects' materials, it will affect their color also.  But some variant of white shouldn't mess you up too much!

[image]

Comment: Yes it's a workable way in Rendered mode with Scene World checked. He still said it didn't work maybe he want that unchecked? I'm not sure. But I find another way inspired by your answer. Since comment cannot post image I'll edit my answer.

Comment: When I check the Scene World checkbox, it changes the color of everything in my scene.  That is not what I want.  I only want to change the color of the floor itself.

Comment: @Neil -- it doesn't actually change the material colors on your other objects, but rather is like blending colors, as if you changed/colored your room lighting.   If you want a dark background (object), your only choice is to create a object (e.g., plane mesh) "behind" your other objects, and use a material with your color of choice.

Comment: @james_t I think you are right.  I will have to design my own workaround.  Blender won't give me what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to change background color that can be seen and only in Solid mode. Switch "Theme" to "Viewport" and change the color below.

[image]

---

Inspired by james_t's answer. There another way to do it in Rendered mode with Scene World unchecked. Go to World Properties and change the Viewport Display - Color.

[image]

Comment: The needle in the haystack was found !

Comment: My interface is different than yours, I could not figure out how to add an image to this comment so I edited my original post to add it.

Comment: It's because mine is using Solid mode and can only be used in Solid mode whereas yours is in Rendered mode. I'm sorry that this solution does have its limitation.

Comment: @AbrahamReinhardt I see what you are saying, I did not realize the drop down box was relevant in all the modes.  Unfortunately, Solid mode makes all my objects gray and translucent.  That is a bigger problem.
Also, I tried going to World Properties and setting the Viewport Display color and it did not change anything either.  I will add a picture to my original post.